# SQL Store varchar or int when I have only a set of values

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I would like to know if it is better (subjective i know) to store an integer of values or a string of values when the field only has a set of possible values.  E.g.

```
 Person Table
 1.
 Name Age Category
 Joe  25  0
 Jane 28  2
 John 22  1

 2.
 Name Age Category
 Joe  25  Student
 Jane 28  Teacher
 John 22  Staff
```

Which method is advisable?  Method 1 is probably faster and better for querying, however, there is more programming cost when displaying data.

Method 2 is probably slower, more expressive and less programming cost.

Any advise will be useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And a grad student can't teach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would generally do this using a reference table, with the category, and an integer for linking the tables.

A reference table has multiple advantages:

- The list of possible values is available in one place.  This is handy, for instance, for generating a list in an application.
- There are no misspellings.
- You can store additional information, such as a short name, a long description, honorific, etc.
- If you need multi-lingual support, you have all the values in a single place.
- The same values can be shared across multiple tables.

Sometimes, a reference table isn't appropriate.  For instance, you might have just two values, `ON` and `OFF`.  You can validate the values using a CHECK CONSTRAINT in most databases.  That is a reasonable alternative.  But I suspect that the category has more information than just a handful of values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and advice.  Option 1 is preferred

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for a simple respons but, I woud like share my method, 
I have a Table named CustomCaptions.
You can find here the structure of the table.

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomCaptions](
[Capt_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Capt_Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Capt_Family] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Capt_FR] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_EN] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_ES] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_IT] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_TR] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_CS] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_DE] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Capt_Deleted] [bit] NULL,
[Capt_Order] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomCaptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Capt_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The Capt_Family column is the name of your foreign column.

In your case, in the CustomCaptions Table, I keep the code and the family. 
For exemple,

```
      Capt_Family     Capt_Code     Capt_EN ... Capt_Order
      Category        0             Student     0
      Category        1             Teacher     1
      Category        2             Staff       2
```

Such, for all little tables like category, status, type etc... I use only one table, this reduces the total count of tables in my db.
Also, I have only one methode to fill comboboxes or listboxes by giving only the family name. And also only one screen to edit the content of any list.

And also as you can see in the table structure, you can manage multi language easily in your application.
Depending your need, you can use Capt_EN or another column for another language.

Finaly, if you wish, you can create views which will reduce the programming cost.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to use a single lookup table for multiple entities.  If your project is small enough, you can probably get away with it, but it has the potential to cause problems eventually.

Comment: Hi jerrad, thanks for yor comment. This system is used in a product which has more than 5 millions of users. May be this is not the best practice but there are many advantages of this system. Especially, if you want to reduce the developpment cost like Dudedolf.

Comment: You may think you're reducing development cost at first, but think about the future.  What if you want to add an additional field to a caption family?  For example, maybe there's a prefix used for generating ID badge numbers (Students ID numbers start with 11, Teachers with 22, and Staff with 33).  You would need to add some sort of Prefix column that only applies to "Category" Capt_Family types, and would be unused by all the others.  Also, how do you have a foreign key constraint against one of your codes?

Comment: What @Jerrad said.  And in addition, putting different languages hardcoded to different columns is not a good design.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative